# Function is not called when button is clicked but works fine in console

Tags: javascript

I am trying to call a function with a specific parameter when button is clicked but it just won't work. Functions playRock and playRound work when tested in console but not with event listener. Please let me know what the problem is, I spent 8h trying to make it work.

It may have something to do with my lack of understanding how callback functions work. I could really use an example on how to call function playRound('rock') when button is pressed.

All examples I found online would have functions without parameters in them or a confusing callback functions.

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="rockbtn">Rock</button>
    <button id="papertn">Paper</button>
    <button id="scissorsbtn">Scissors</button>


    <script>
        // Call PlayRock upon clicking button #rockbtn
        const rockbtn = document.querySelector('#rockbtn');
        rockbtn.addEventListener('click', playRock);

        // Call function playRound with propery 'rock'
        function playRock() {
            result = playRound('rock');
            return result
        }

        // Randomly selects computer's choice out of rock, paper or scissors
       function computerPlay() {
           const choices = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors'];
           let choice = choices[Math.floor(Math.random()*choices.length)];
           return choice
       }

       // Plays round of rock, paper, scissors between computer and player
       function playRound(playerSelection) {
            playerSelection = playerSelection.toLowerCase();
            computerSelection = computerPlay();
            let result;

            if (playerSelection !== 'rock' & playerSelection !== 'paper' & playerSelection !== 'scissors'){
                result = 'There is no such choice. Please choose either rock, paper or scissors.';

            } else if (playerSelection === computerSelection) {
                result = 'It is a draw!';

            } else if (playerSelection === 'rock' & computerSelection === 'paper') {
                result = 'You lost! Paper beats rock.';

            } else if (playerSelection === 'rock' & computerSelection === 'scissors') { 
                result = 'You won! Rock beats scissors.';

            } else if (playerSelection === 'paper' & computerSelection === 'scissors') {
                result = 'You lost! Scissors beat paper.';
        
            } else if (playerSelection === 'paper' & computerSelection === 'rock') {
                result = 'You won! Paper beats rock.';

            } else if (playerSelection === 'scissors' & computerSelection === 'paper') {
                result = 'You won! Scissors beat paper.';

            } else if (playerSelection === 'scissors' & computerSelection === 'rock') {
                result = 'You lost! Rock beats scissors.';
            }

            return result
       }

      /* function game() {
           let playerScore = 0;
           let computerScore = 0;
           let finalResult;
    
           for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
               let outcome = playRound();

               if (roundResult = outcome.includes('won')) {
                   playerScore += 1;
                   console.log('You won this round!');
               } else if (roundResult = outcome.includes('lost')) {
                   computerScore += 1;
                   console.log('You won this round!');
               } else {
                   console.log('This round ended in a draw!');
               }
           }

           if (playerScore > computerScore) {
               finalResult = `Congratulations! You won ${playerScore} to ${computerScore}!`;
           } else {
               finalResult = `You lost ${playerScore} to ${computerScore}`;
           }

           return finalResult;
       }

       */
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

```js
// Call PlayRock upon clicking button #rockbtn
const rockbtn = document.querySelector('#rockbtn');
rockbtn.addEventListener('click', playRock);

// Call function playRound with propery 'rock'
function playRock() {
  result = playRound('rock');
  return result
}

// Randomly selects computer's choice out of rock, paper or scissors
function computerPlay() {
  const choices = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors'];
  let choice = choices[Math.floor(Math.random() * choices.length)];
  return choice
}

// Plays round of rock, paper, scissors between computer and player
function playRound(playerSelection) {
  playerSelection = playerSelection.toLowerCase();
  computerSelection = computerPlay();
  let result;

  if (playerSelection !== 'rock' & playerSelection !== 'paper' & playerSelection !== 'scissors') {
    result = 'There is no such choice. Please choose either rock, paper or scissors.';

  } else if (playerSelection === computerSelection) {
    result = 'It is a draw!';

  } else if (playerSelection === 'rock' & computerSelection === 'paper') {
    result = 'You lost! Paper beats rock.';

  } else if (playerSelection === 'rock' & computerSelection === 'scissors') {
    result = 'You won! Rock beats scissors.';

  } else if (playerSelection === 'paper' & computerSelection === 'scissors') {
    result = 'You lost! Scissors beat paper.';

  } else if (playerSelection === 'paper' & computerSelection === 'rock') {
    result = 'You won! Paper beats rock.';

  } else if (playerSelection === 'scissors' & computerSelection === 'paper') {
    result = 'You won! Scissors beat paper.';

  } else if (playerSelection === 'scissors' & computerSelection === 'rock') {
    result = 'You lost! Rock beats scissors.';
  }

  return result
}

/* function game() {
           let playerScore = 0;
           let computerScore = 0;
           let finalResult;
    
           for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
               let outcome = playRound();

               if (roundResult = outcome.includes('won')) {
                   playerScore += 1;
                   console.log('You won this round!');
               } else if (roundResult = outcome.includes('lost')) {
                   computerScore += 1;
                   console.log('You won this round!');
               } else {
                   console.log('This round ended in a draw!');
               }
           }

           if (playerScore > computerScore) {
               finalResult = `Congratulations! You won ${playerScore} to ${computerScore}!`;
           } else {
               finalResult = `You lost ${playerScore} to ${computerScore}`;
           }

           return finalResult;
       }

       */
```

```html
<button id="rockbtn">Rock</button>
<button id="papertn">Paper</button>
<button id="scissorsbtn">Scissors</button>
```

Comment: Please provide the full HTML/JS code.

Comment: Is your javascript ABOVE or BELOW your HTML?

Comment: your functions - `playRock` and `playRound` - don't actually *do* anything when called. They assign to some variables and return a result, but just calling those on click isn't going to actually do anything the user can see. Presumably when you say it works from the console, you mean it prints the return value - well that's what the console does. But event handler functions don't do anything with their return value.

Comment: Also, what are you doing with **result**? I don't see any alert, console or anything.

Comment: Please provide the HTML. Many times people put the ```<script src>```tag at the top of the page or the top of the body tag, and the script is being loaded before the HTML itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In functions, when you **return** something, that is just passing that data to the caller of that function. It doesn't show it to the user.

In the below example, the user will not have any clue that aa was returned as it isn't being shown or alerted in anyway.

```
function test(){
   return test2("aa");
}

function test2(str){
 return str;
}
```

For learning, at the end of **function playRound(playerSelection) {**

just add **alert(result);**

That will just popup a message to the user telling them the result. There are many other ways to do this, this is just the easiest for learning.

you can also use **console.log(result);** to show the results in the console.

In the below code, I add a class to all of the buttons, and use a data attribute to hold the button's action (ie rock, paper, scissors).

Then in the javascript I loop through the buttons and add an event handler to each that grabs that data attribute and passes it to playRound.

For testing, I didn't use your for playRound function, mine is for demo purposes only.

```js
let btns = document.querySelectorAll(".btn");

function playRound(action){
console.log(action)
}

btns.forEach(function(el){
  el.addEventListener("click",function(e){
    playRound(e.target.getAttribute("data-action"));
  });
});
```

```html
<button class="btn" data-action="rock">Rock</button>
<button class="btn" data-action="paper">Paper</button>
<button class="btn" data-action="scissors">Scissors</button>
```

Comment: Actually, using `console.log(result)` is better than an `alert()` because an `alert` is modal and will lock the UI.

Comment: Thank you. When I added alert(result) it actually does return what I was looking for. As I understand, button was calling the function but I simply did not see result anywhere, including the console. Console.log(result) also works, I just made a mistake assuming that return would show up in console without console.log.

Comment: @ScottMarcus, you are correct, I updated my answer

Comment: @imvain2 Is there any way for me to get rid of playRock function and somehow pass playRound('rock') with addEventListener? Because it seems like addEventListener calls function as long as it has no parameter but in this case I need string 'rock' as parameter. I will have 3 buttons and each will run same function but with different parameters.